# Android: ClassNotFoundException when referring newly added Activity

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio, classnotfoundexception

My app has been running fine both on device and in emulator, but after adding a new activity, this code throws a ClassNotFoundException:

```
startActivity(new Intent(this, TutorialActivity.class));
```

This is the build.gradle file for the project:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.5.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'android'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 17
    buildToolsVersion "18.1"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 7
        targetSdkVersion 16
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:13.0.+'
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
}
```

And this is the Paths screen in Android Studio:

[image]

The projects build without error. I am using Android Studio build 0.2.10.
Any idea what the problem is?

Comment: have declared this activity in manifest file?

Comment: Did you add your new activity in manifest....?

Comment: have you define new activity in AndroidManifest.xml ???

Comment: Yes, sorry I didn't include the manifest file, but it is declared there the same way as my other activities.

Comment: 0. did you clean and rebuild all? 1. which class name is reported in the error message? 2. Try to replace TutorialActivity.class with the class of some other activity. Will the error disappear?

Comment: I had a directory under the libs directory. When I deleted that it worked...